# install sonata userbundle in symfony2.4.1

Tags: symfony-2.4, sonata-user-bundle

i want to install sonata userbundle and i use symfony2.4.1, this is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
    "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.2"
```

when i run the command:
 `php composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle:2.1.1`

i got this error message:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle 2.1.1 -> satisfiable b
y sonata-project/user-bundle[2.1.1].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.4.1
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 2.1.1 requires symfony/security >=2.1,<2.3-dev
-> satisfiable by symfony/security[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2
.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v
2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8,
 v2.2.9].
- don't install symfony/security v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- don't install symfony/security v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.4.1

- Installation request for symfony/symfony == 2.4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symf
ony/symfony[v2.4.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So what is the the version of sonata userbundle compatible with symfony2.4.1??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i solve this problem by using the following command:

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle:2.2.4
```